Have regex skip a match if it occurs within 1024 characters
I have the following regex.replace:
self.reply = raw_reply.replace(b"<" + rcid + b":", b"") 

where rcid is a command reference. raw_reply is a huge mass of data in bytes e.g.
<35:\x07\x98c\x45\x09 etc. 

I want it to remove all instances of, for example <35: but only if one has not been replaced less than 1024 characters ago.
Is there a way to do this with regex?
I've tried looking at exclusions and negative lookahead but not sure how to implement it when i want it to ignore any matches within 1024 characters of the previous match.

Split and code?

That's not a regexp replace, it's a simple string replace. Regexp replace is re.sub().

Use a regular expression that matches up to 1024 characters after the pattern you're replacing. Capture the excess 1024 characters in a capture group so you can copy them to the replacement. The next match will have to be after this, since overlapping matches are not processed.
self.reply = re.sub(b"<" + rcid + b":(.{,1024})", br"\1", raw_reply, flags=re.DOTALL)


Thank you Barmar! I have tried this and it gets rid of all instances of '<35:', not just every 1024 characters.
Here is a better data example:
string = b"<35:y\nv\nu\nt\nv\nw<35:nw\nv\ny\nx\nv\n{\nz\nr\nv\nr\nr\ny\nw\nx\nv\nx\n{\nv\nr\nt\nu\nz\n|\nx\nv\nt\ns\nx\nw\ns\nt\nx\nu\nz\nq\nt\nu\nt\nv\nv\nx\ny\nw\nr\nr\nt\nu\nt\nw\nv\nv\nt\nv\ny\ns\ns\nv\nt\nt\nv\nr\nw\nu\nu\nv\ns\nv\nz\nx\np\n|\nt\nr\n|\nq\nt\nu\nt\nt\nv\nv\nu\nn\ny\nw\nv\nw\nx\nw\ns..."
I want to get rid of the first <35: but this re.sub gets rid of both. What do you recommend?
Thank you!! :)

I didn't realize there could be newlines in the string, so it needs flags=re.DOTALL to match them.

Thank you so much! that worked wonderfully!!!! :) Thank you thank you!

What to do when someone answers your question
